# How do i allow a user to pick a song from their iPod library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipod

For my app, an alarm, i'd like the user to be able to pick a song to play from their iPod library. How would i go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not know the details, but have you read the [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)?